# Is it true that, for each $\alpha\in[0,1],$ at least one of the functions $x\mapsto f(x,\alpha)$ and $y\mapsto f(\alpha,y)$ has to be R-integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

> Suppose $f:[0,1]\times[0,1]\to\Bbb R$ is R-integrable. Is it true that, for each $\alpha\in[0,1],$ at least one of the functions $x\mapsto f(x,\alpha)$ and $y\mapsto f(\alpha,y)$ has to be R-integrable?

I've seen [an example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3452182/iterated-integral-exist-but-the-fuction-is-not-riemann-integrable/3452742#3452742) of a non-R integrable function $f:[0,1]\times[0,1]\to\Bbb R,$ $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}1,&x\in\Bbb Q\\ 2y,&x\notin\Bbb Q\end{cases}$$

In this example, $y\mapsto f(\alpha,y)$ is integrable, but $x\mapsto f(x,\alpha)$ fails to be $\forall\alpha\in[0,1]\setminus\left\{\frac12\right\}$ and so does $f$ over $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ as proven by RRL.

I tried building something from the answer in the thread, but I couldn't find any example of a function that isn't integrable "along any segment in $[0,1]\times[0,1].$ Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You can also show that if $f$ is Riemann integrable on any product of intervals $A \times B$. Then $\int_A f(x,\alpha) \, dx$ exists for almost every $\alpha \in B$  and $\int_B f(\alpha,y) \, dy$ exists for almost every $\alpha \in A$.

Comment: @RRL, in this context, _almost every_ means  _except for finitely many_ ?

Comment: It means except for $\alpha$ in a set of Lebesgue measure zero which could possibly be infinite.

Comment: So if $\int_{A \times B} f$ exists as a Riemann integral you could never have $\int_A f(x,\alpha) \,dx$ not exist for $\alpha$ in some interval or any set of positive measure.

Comment: @RRL, thank you! I'm going to think more about it in the morning and than maybe follow-up, if that's okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the simplest possible function that is Riemann integrable on the square and yet fails to be Riemann integrable on both $x=0$ and $y=0$. Take, for example, the function
$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 0, & x=0, y\in\Bbb Q \text{ or } y=0, x\in\Bbb Q \\
1, & x=0, y\notin\Bbb Q \text{ or } y=0, x\notin\Bbb Q \\
5, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much! I should've thought of that myself...

Comment: Yup, @Winter. Ordinarily, I would have encouraged you to do so in the chat, but you didn't respond to my queries.